# How to store several checkbox using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to save into my database the checkbox I checked into my view. I have a `title`, a `type_article` (dropdown), the `theme` (checkbox) and `contents`.

I'm doing this in `article_list.blade.view` :

```
@foreach ($themes as $theme)  
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="themeCheckbox[]" value="{{ $theme->theme_id }}">
     <label class="form-check-label">{{ $theme->nom_theme }}</label>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

My `AdminController` :

```
    public function createArticle(Request $request)
    {
       $data = $request->validate([ // $data = $this->validate($request
        'titreArticle' => 'bail|required|between:5,40',
        'typeArticle' => 'bail|required',
        'themeCheckbox' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'themeCheckbox.*' => 'required|string|distinct|exists:theme,nom_theme',
        'contenuArticle' => 'bail|required',
       ]);
       $type_articles = Type_article::findOrFail($data['typeArticle']);
       $article = new Article();
       $article->type_article()->associate($type_articles);
       $themes = Theme::whereIn('nom_theme', $data['themeCheckbox'])->get();
       $article->theme()->associate($themes);
       $article->titre = $data['titreArticle'];
       $article->contenu = $data['contenuArticle'];
       $article->date_creation = date('Y-m-d');
       $article->save();
       $article->theme()->attach($themes);

       return view('admin/panel_admin/panel_admin');
   }
```

Everything is good except the checkbox issue. I do show my error inside my view and thats what appear when I submit the 3 checkboxs :

```
The selected themeCheckbox.0 is invalid.
The selected themeCheckbox.1 is invalid.
The selected themeCheckbox.2 is invalid.
```

I do have a pivot table (Article and Theme as table and Article_theme the pivot table).

EDIT :

The problem was `$themes = Theme::whereIn('nom_theme', $data['themeCheckbox'])->get();`, I need to change `nom_theme` to `id_theme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `$theme->theme_id` to the name array of the checkbox. Then, check whether the *id* exists or not in the array, because default behavior of checkbox is to remove unchecked items.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="themeCheckbox[{{$theme->theme_id}}]" value="1">
```

I set value of checkbox to 1, it means when you check it, a value of 1 will be assigned to the key of `$theme->theme_id`. A sample output of this checkbox is something like below:

```
themeCheckbox=[
    '1' => '1';
    '2' => '1';
    '3' => '1';
    '4' => '1';
    '5' => '1';
];
```

So, you must look for the keys in your code, not the values as they are unique (1). Modify your controller as below and use `array_keys()` method in it:

```
$themes = Theme::whereIn('nom_theme', array_keys($data['themeCheckbox']))->get();
```

### Update

Remove unnecessary validation `'themeCheckbox' => 'required|array|min:1',` and fix the other one like below:

```
'themeCheckbox.*' => 'required',
```

Comment: Hello, first thank you for the help. I added what you asked me and I have this error below my form : `The selected themeCheckbox.$theme->theme_id is invalid.` As I said, I've a `pivot` table with my `id_article` and `theme_id`

Comment: I forgot to add `{{` and `}}` in `name="themeCheckbox[$theme->theme_id]"`. I've modified it in the answer.

Comment: I've this error now `The themeCheckbox.1 field has a duplicate value.
The themeCheckbox.3 field has a duplicate value.` when I check the 1st and 3rd checkbox.

Comment: @Leon pay attention to the Update in the answer and fix the validation

Comment: Nvm, didn't saw the update. Now i've this error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::associate()` I guess I have this error since in `Article` model, I'm doing this : `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Theme', 'themes_articles', 'id_article', 'theme_id');` and inside my controller `$article->theme()->associate($themes);`. I've the **belongsToMany** relationship and the **associate** function. With what should I replace `associate()` ?

Comment: This is another question @Leon. You need to grasp some basics about relationship. I suggest you reading [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) carefully as you're trying to pass multiple *theme* to belongTo relationship. Maybe you should get `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: I do not have this error anymore, I forgot to add this `$article->theme()->attach($themes);` The article is created but now, I have nothing inside my pivot table, its empty... Could we go through the chat to check this problem please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227381/discussion-between-leon-and-babak-ashrafi).